# Calling PHP function each time a div is dropped

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a draggable element and I would like to call PHP function each time the element is dropped (basically to save its position - pixels from top and left to mysql database). How to approach it? AJAX?

Comment: Yes, Ajax would be the way to go.

Comment: yes. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function() {
        $.get('http://mysite.com/dragged.php?droppedID='+this.id);
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

If you want the id of the draggable (and not what it was dropped on), you need to use the `ui` parameter when you setup the `drop` callback:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
$("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $.get('http://mysite.com/dragged.php?droppedID='+ui.draggable.attr('id'));
    }
});
```

Comment: nice, but not very safe as anyone can change it by typing the address with parameters.

Comment: @Vafello - It's an example. A Session ID may be required; that's the OPs decision. ;)

Comment: No simplier way to just call the fucntion from the same file? Without sessions?

Comment: @Vafello - Whoops, sorry, didn't realize you were the OP. What do you mean by the first question and "from the same file"?

Comment: Sorry, 'from the same file' was unclear. I am just wondering if I could call the php function safely without sessions etc.?

Comment: @Vafello - Well... I suppose you could include a cookie or a hidden input with a value somewhere on the page (and send it back with the request to the server, either in a cookie or appended to the URL). You can't call a PHP function without sending a request back to the server, so any way you could protect that type of communication would be valid.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX sounds like a very good idea, yes.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery HTTP methods. It is more simple than AJAX, I always use it!